How can a GPU directly access memory data created by the CPU while maintaining real-time synchronization?
I hope to use the GPU on a mobile phone to directly and quickly access and synchronize memory data, which the CPU will also read and modify in real-time.
On a mobile phone, this is a simple example, where the printed result is "1 7" instead of "7 7". It's known that active synchronization can be achieved using methods like enqueueReadBuffer or enqueueNDRangeKernel, but is there a way to achieve automatic synchronization? Ideally, the GPU should be able to read the real-time updated values of data directly after modification.
   data = (int*)mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    data[0] = 1;
    
    cl::Buffer inputBuffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR , sizeof(int) * dataSize, data, &err);
    cl::Buffer outputBuffer = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(int) * dataSize, NULL, &err);
    
    cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(kernelSource2, strlen(kernelSource2) + 1));
    cl::Program program(context, source);
    err = program.build(devices);
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "square", &err);
    kernel.setArg(0, inputBuffer);
    kernel.setArg(1, outputBuffer);
    
    data[0] = 7;
    size_t globalSize = dataSize;
    cl::Event event;
    err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(globalSize), cl::NullRange, nullptr, &event);
    int *result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * dataSize);
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * dataSize, result);
    printf("%d %d\n", result[0], data[0])


Probably not what you want to hear, but I'm highly doubtful that you can do this in OpenCL, and if you could, the performance would probably be terrible. There are some exotic vendor specific extensions which might interest you like Shared Virtual Memory https://www.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/tutorial-svm-basic.pdf but I don;t know if there's anything like it for ARM. I also thought I read somewhere it was deprecated. Sorry, don;t know much about it. Also https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/extensions/arm/cl_arm_shared_virtual_memory.txt
